# How is the Neutron capture cross section of Xenon-135 so high?

Tags: nuclear-physics, neutrons, scattering-cross-section

Xenon-135 has a Neutron capture cross section of 2-3 million barns, this is equivalent in area to a disk with a radius of 8-10pm. The cross sectional area of a Uranium nucleus is roughly 1 barn. The atomic radius of Xenon-135 is only a little over 100pm, and it has a bohr radius of 1pm.

How does it achieve such a large cross section?

Comment: In this paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022310773900956#:~:text=The%20neutron%20capture%20cross-section%20of%20135%20Xe%20has,%28Co%20%28n%2C%20%CE%B3%29%20cross%20section%20of%2037%C2%B709%20barns. the authors discuss their  measurement of the cross section and they attribute the high cross section of 135Xe  to "

Comment: "The large cross-section of 135Xe for neutrons is due to a broad resonance near 
0.084 eV, thus cross-sections measured in nuclear reactors are neutron temperature 
dependent and a comparison of measured 135Xe cross-sections can be made only where 
temperatures were also determined. "

Comment: Indeed, as @annav says, you need to look at the energy dependence. ENDF shows quite clearly that the (n,g) reaction dominates the overall cross section up to about 10eV. By 1MeV the capture cross section is 3 orders of magnitude down from the total.